# Двоеточие перед системой уравнений

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

Сначала пример:

[image: пример системы уравнений]

Вопрос: **Нужно ли ставить двоеточие после подкрашенных слов и почему именно нужно или не нужно?**

Я рассуждаю так:

Если думать, что *система уравнений* -- это обобщающее слово [т.е. система уравнений -- это родовое понятие (общее), по отношению к которому однородные члены предложения -- отдельные уравнения -- являются видовыми понятиями (частными)], то двоеточие необходимо.

Если же слова *система уравнений* понимать как словесное обозначение последующего математического объекта, то двоеточие не нужно. Между прочим, в исходной разметке LaTeX система уравнений -- это цельный объект. По смыслу же, после слов  *система уравнений* в данном случае нельзя вставить *а именно*, так как смысл (или интонация при чтении?) поменяется. Со словами *а именно* автор считает новостью, что получена вообще хоть какая-то система уравнений. Без этих слов факт получения системы уравнений вообще не является новостью, новость -- только конкретная система. Я так это понимаю.

Answer (score 3):

Структура предложения в данном случае допускает вариативность постановки двоеточия. С одной стороны, мы можем трактовать предложение таким образом: "умножая ..., с помощью ... получаем систему уравнений (1)" (Ваша вторая трактовка). С другой стороны, возможна такая трактовка: "умножая ..., с помощью ... получаем **такую** систему уравнений: ..." (Ваша первая трактовка).

[Пример без двоеточия](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=MEiAAAAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwgaqkkK3uAhXlsIsKHRaHD5k4FBDoATAJegQIBxAC).
[Пример с двоеточием](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=dsqxAAAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjnlODrjq3uAhXWHXcKHUn8BroQ6AEwCHoECAcQAg).

(Примеры я ищу с помощью поиска по гугло-книгам, просматривая ссылки примерно [по таким запросам](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&biw=1138&bih=506&tbm=bks&ei=Y4IJYKCRBqWvrgSh6ZZI&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%20OR%20%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22&oq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%20OR%20%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4791.15989.0.16337.9.9.0.0.0.0.176.1100.0j8.8.0....0...1c.1j2.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.tyYzzgRFTws).)

В традициях физико-математической литературы двоеточие в подобных предложениях не ставится (я не смог найти ни одного хорошего примера с двоеточием). Но в точно таких же предложениях в других науках двоеточие ставится намного чаще (если не вообще чаще). Постановка двоеточия не будет ошибкой, но лучше всё же соблюдать существующие традиции. И в любом случае необходимо выдержать всю книгу в одном стиле.

PS. Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание, что в Вашем предложении пропущена запятая (скорее всего, после слов "и т.д."), закрывающая деепричастный оборот.

Comment: Спасибо за P.S. Два корректора пропустили ошибку.